# .htaccess can not/will not access /error/ directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to setup custom error pages.

I put the pages in /error/ in the document root. However, I think this may have a conflict as .htaccess can not access the file I specified.

I did set AllowOverride All in my apache config file.

If I go to /error/, a 403 error appears.

I can confirm that my .htaccess is being read, because if I enter some random text into the .htaccess, it will return a internal server error.

rewriting is enabled.

Here is my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

<Files .htaccess> 
order allow,deny 
deny from all 
</Files> 

ErrorDocument 404 /error/noexist.html
```

If I put the error page in the document root and set it in the htaccess, it will read fine.

The problem is that it can't read the contents of the /error/ directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/error/` is a directory, right? The default Apache configuration is to return a `403 Forbidden` status when trying to access the root of a directory that does not contain an index page *unless* `Options +Indexes` is set, which will cause the server to automatically generate and show a list of files and subdirectories.

If you want the error page to show in this case, you could try adding the same ErrorDocument line with `404` changed to `403`.

Comment: I don't think that is the case. For example, my /images/ directory lists all the images.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set directory permissions?

```
<Directory "C:/path/to/htdocs/error">
Options FollowSymLinks
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I think this requires access to Apache's httpd.conf, though. Do you have access to that?